# Rails and Postgresql Migration change column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

I need to change the column type from time to datetime in rails.I cant't change the column type.It show this error

```
"rake aborted!
 StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "fun_from" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
 : ALTER TABLE "general_infos" ALTER COLUMN "fun_from" TYPE timestamp/home/PCA/db/migrate/20150730102811_change_data_type_in_general_infos.rb:3:in `change'
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "fun_from" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
 HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
:     ALTER TABLE "general_infos" ALTER COLUMN "fun_from" TYPE timestamp
/home/PCA/db/migrate/20150730102811_change_data_type_in_general_infos.rb:3:in `change'
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "fun_from" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
/home/PCA/db/migrate/20150730102811_change_data_type_in_general_infos.rb:3:in `change'"
```

Below format i tried,

```
change_column(:table_name, :column_name, :datetime )
```

and also tried below format

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'datetime USING CAST(column_name AS datetime)'
```

psql version - 9.4.4 & Any one give me solution.

Comment: Please format the error messages in such a way that (1) they are not bold, and (2) Are blocks of code, similar to the two lines at the end of your post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522520/rails-postgres-migration-to-change-colomn-gives-error-cannot-be-cast-to-type?answertab=active#tab-top).  Net net is that you should drop the existing column and add the datetime column as there is no reasonable way to generate datetimes from times.

Comment: i won't drop that column.if i removed that column and also removed its values.